# how scala know from where to download dependencies?

Tags: scala, build, dependency-management

I'm working on scala project, where I'm using some third party libraries and those libraries are available at centralized repository (I've a url to download those).

May I know please, how scala know from where to download dependencies ? Where I can use repo url to download dependencies in scala project ?

Like in case of java, I used to mention jars repo url in setting.xml file, from where It could fetch too dependencies.

Comment: The scala compiler does not download dependencies (neither does the Java compiler). Your build system (sbt, mvn, gradle etc.) does. So look into how your build system handles dependencies.

Comment: In sbt https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Resolvers.html